# Linux (Ubuntu) Run program in background

Tags: linux, php

I am trying to run a PHP script in background on my Linux server over SSH (Putty) but I'm not getting this to work.

The command I want to run in background is:

`php buildscript/build_css.php` as `root@FIG-VMSAM:/var/www/wem#`

I have tried this and get only this and not working, ( do not build my CSS for me )

```
root@FIG-VMSAM:/var/www/wem# php buildscript/build_css.php &
[1] 2274

[1]+  Stopped                 php buildscript/build_css.php
```

I has also try start the command by normal and after this put this on background by `<Ctrl>+z`  but it does not work either.

As background in my PHP Script I use `system()` and call `stylus` http://learnboost.github.com/stylus/
and `inotifywait` if this is to help?

Does someone know why this doesn't work for me?

Comment: Does the script run fine when in foreground? Because I think it stops due to an error.

Comment: Yes this work very good in foreground while I run this normal but not in background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another quick answer is..assumming that the program really needs no user input:

```
 php buildscript/build_css.php </dev/null &
```

The reason it is stopping is that the program is opening `stdin` for some reason, eventhough it might not need any input.

Comment: Very Good, this work for me, I will be happy to not need to has 5 terminals open at same time.

Answer (score 1):

Would it be possible to run the script in a separate screen?

`sudo apt-get install screen`

Then use `screen -S screenname` where screenname is a name you give the screen session.

Once in the screen, you can then enter your command, `php buildscript/build_css.php`

To leave the session, use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd>.

To get back into the session, use `screen -r screenname`

Do not worry, when you leave the session, the command will stay running in the background.

Comment: I will test, that the commando will be runing after I close putty is not what I want, Hope I can in this case tun this off.

Comment: When you exit putty, the screen session will continue to run.

Comment: Sorry Try this but by some way the `screen` do not work very well on my server.

Comment: When you are in the screen session, are you in the proper directory?

Comment: Can I leave the screen by a comando? Or start a new screen with a comando then automatic left the new screen?

Comment: You can leave the screen by pressing <ctrl>+a+d